# Bind more than 1 port over SSH?

Tags: server, ssh, bind, port-forwarding, tunnel

I use SSH for managing linux servers. Sometimes I need to bind ports from the server to my client. I do this this way:

`sudo ssh <serverUser>@<server> -L <localPort>:localhost:<serverPort>`

Now sometimes I run into situations where I would like to bind several ports, like for instance port 80, port 443, port 8080, ...

Is that possible over SSH port binding?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested multiple `-L` parameters on the same SSH command and it worked.

`sudo ssh <serverUser>@<server> -L 80:localhost:80 -L 443:localhost:443`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was looking for quite some time for this and now, 5 minutes after posting the question here, one possibility pops to my head.

Open multiple terminals and bin the different needed ports one after one to the same server.

For instance:

On terminal 1:
`sudo ssh <serverUser>@<server> -L 80:localhost:80`

On terminal 2:
`sudo ssh <serverUser>@<server> -L 443:localhost:443`

On terminal 3:
`sudo ssh <serverUser>@<server> -L 8080:localhost:8080`